# transfer virtualenvwrapper environment from ubuntu to windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualenvwrapper

I've worked on different projects with several virtual environments, in ubuntu.
I had virtualenvwrapper and did that with the classical `mkvirtualenv <envname>` command.

On my system I also have windows and i'd like to retrieve my environments on this os.
I installed through pip the virtualenvwrapper-win package and set my WORKON_HOME environment variable to be at the same place as on my ubuntu system.

Now on windows, the output of the workon command is the following :

```
(base) C:\Users\mathi>workon

Pass a name to activate one of the following virtualenvs:
==============================================================================
caps_env
dashex
media
PMALL36
```

But when I try to activate one of the environment I get :

```
(base) C:\Users\mathi>workon PMALL36

    D:\Informatique\virtual_environments\PMALL36
    doesn't contain a virtualenv (yet).
    Create it with "mkvirtualenv PMALL36"
```

Any clue ?

Comment: The error message you posted contains a solution.

Comment: But the environment exists already. When I type `mkvirtualenv PMALL36` it says : `(base) C:\Users\mathi>mkvirtualenv PMALL36

    ERROR: virtualenv "PMALL36" already exists`

Comment: Don't you think that information is somewhat important? Important information needs to go into your question. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of the virtualenvs are different between linux and windows, as are the python executables and all modules written in C and loaded as shared libraries.  Any third party packages will have problems if they are not pure Python modules, and even then they're installed in different locations, e.g. on windows:

```
F:\> workon test1
(test1) F:\> cdvirtualenv
(test1) c:\srv\venv\test1> cdsitepackages
(test1) c:\srv\venv\test1\Lib\site-packages>
```

and Ubuntu:

```
deployer@linoidbc:~$ workon test1
(test1) deployer@linoidbc:~$ cdvirtualenv
(test1) deployer@linoidbc:/srv/venv/test1$ cdsitepackages
(test1) deployer@linoidbc:/srv/venv/test1/lib/python2.7/site-packages$
```

I'm guessing you've created the virtualenv from linux, which puts activate in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate` and you're getting that error message when virtualenvwrapper-win checks for it in `%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\activate.bat`:

```
if not exist "%WORKON_HOME%\%VENV%\Scripts\activate.bat" (
    echo.
    echo.    %WORKON_HOME%\%VENV%
    echo.    doesn't contain a virtualenv ^(yet^).
    echo.    Create it with "mkvirtualenv %VENV%"
    goto END
)
```

You should instead create a shared (project) directory, separate from your virtualenvs. You need to create two virtualenvs, one for linux and one for windows, and connect them to the project directory.  I believe you should be able to do it with:

```
mkvirtualenv -a /path/to/project/dir mylinux_venv
```

and

```
mkvirtualenv -a \path\to\project\dir mywin_venv
```

put your requirements.txt file in the project directory and use `pip install -U -r requirements.txt` from both virtualenvs when you change your requirements.

The project directory is automatically added to the path of the corresponding virtualenv, and the `cdproject` command will change directory to it.